# How to set a value of a key of a user-defined (not global or default) style through /utils/exec (or similar means that allow for code execution)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, pgfkeys

I need to change the value of the `color` key of `changeStyleColor` style through that style's `/utils/exec`.

I can set a value of a global key through `/utils/exec` by `\tikzset{/tikz/myKey=myValue}`, or can set a value of a key located inside a user-defined directory by `\tikzset{/tikz/myDirectory/myKey=myValue}`. But how can I set a value of a key belonging to a user-defined style?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset
  { % global color
    color=orange,
    changeGlobalColor/.style=
      { /utils/exec=
          { \tikzset{/tikz/color=red}
          }
      },
    changeDirectoryColor/.style=
      { /utils/exec=
          { \tikzset{/tikz/directory/color=green}
          }
      },
    directory/.cd,
    color/.initial=blue,
    /tikz/.cd,
    changeStyleColor/.style=
      { /utils/exec=
          { % how to change "pink" to something else?
          },
        color=pink
      }
  }
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % global color, orange (initial)
    \path node(n1){n1};
    % global color, red (changed from orange through /utils/exec)
    \path node(n2)at(n1.south)[changeGlobalColor]{n2};
    % directory color, green (changed from blue through /utils/exec)
    \path node(n3)at(n2.south)[changeDirectoryColor,color=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/directory/color}]{n3};
    % style color, pink (initial); needs to be changed from pink to something else
    %  (through /utils/exec)
    \path node(n4)at(n3.south)[changeStyleColor]{n4};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I find the question very unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following but it is IMHO very much against the spirit of pgf keys in this application.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset
  { % global color
    color=orange,
    changeGlobalColor/.style=
      { /utils/exec=
          { \tikzset{/tikz/color=red}
          }
      },
    changeDirectoryColor/.style=
      { /utils/exec=
          { \tikzset{/tikz/directory/color=green}
          }
      },
    directory/.cd,
    color/.initial=blue,
    /tikz/.cd,
    changeStyleColor/.style=
      { /utils/exec=
          { \tikzset{/tikz/directory/color=#1}
          },
        color=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/directory/color}
      }
  }
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    % global color, orange (initial)
    \path node(n1){n1};
    % global color, red (changed from orange through /utils/exec)
    \path node(n2)at(n1.south)[changeGlobalColor]{n2};
    % directory color, green (changed from blue through /utils/exec)
    \path node(n3)at(n2.south)[changeDirectoryColor,color=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/directory/color}]{n3};
    % style color, pink (initial); needs to be changed from pink to something else
    %  (through /utils/exec)
    \path node(n4)at(n3.south)[changeStyleColor]{n4};
    \path node(n5)at(n4.south)[changeStyleColor=pink]{n5};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]